# Bubble sort em python - Problema em inserir valores na lista

Tags: python-3.x

Colegas, estou com um problema em inserir  valores dentro de um lista, segue o cogido:

```
lista = []

for i in range(0, 4):
   lista[i] = int(input('Informe um numero: '))

for i in range(0, len(lista)-1):
   for j in range(i + 1, len(lista)):
      if lista[i] > lista[j]:
          aux = lista[i]
          lista[i] = lista[j]
          lista[j] = aux

print(lista)
```

Comment: Você nem sequer vai explicar QUAL problema está tendo?!

Comment: O primeiro laço que fiz foi para preencher a lista da erro. Sei que a logica do segundo esta certa pois ja testei com um lista feita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para inserir elementos numa lista, use o método `.append`.

```
lista = []

for i in range(0, 4):
   numero = int(input('Informe um numero: '))
   lista.append(numero)
```

Veja a documentação da linguagem: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html